# primary key and auto increment missing when importing a database mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp, wampserver, wamp3

i exported a database in sql file
when importing it in wampserver 3 i found that the majority of the table has the field id but primary key and auto incremented was not mentionned in the database
i looked to the sql file and i found that there is commands to do it:

for example:

ALTER TABLE `workflowstatus`
  MODIFY `id` int(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=665;

what should i do to have a correct import

Comment: How did you run the import? Via phpMyAdmin or from the command line?

Comment: i used the import via phpmyadmin

Comment: Had a similar issue. In my case, it turned out that the import was stopping at a statement that required more privileges than the current user doing the import had. An error would be displayed in phpmyadmin but every statement after that wasn't being run; the subsequent statements were the ones creating the indexes and implementing autoincrement